# Web services load test with increment variable

Tags: web-development, web-services

I'm trying to  found out some application or way to run a load test on a Web services. 
requests must simultaneous but my big problem is that: for every request, the values passed to a variable long  must increment! 
has any one got any idea ? 
Tnx!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [LoadUI](http://www.loadui.org/) will serve your needs (from the creators of SoapUI).